# how to remotely focus Vim through the clientserver

Tags: clientserver, window-management

I use Linux and usually run Vim in a terminal. Lately, I've been using Vim's clientserver functionality to interact with Vim remotely. I'm wondering if there's a way to focus the terminal/Vim window when interacting with Vim in this way. For example, in one terminal I run Vim as:

```bash
$ vim --servername VIM
```

and in another terminal I call the following command to open a text file in the first terminal:

```bash
$ vim --remote /path/to/file.txt
```

This command is successful, but doesn't focus the first terminal. Note that I tested this in Arch Linux with both Gnome and i3 window manager, and with both `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`.

Also, I've tried using Vim's `foreground()` command via `vim --remote-send ':call foreground()<CR>'`, as well as the `vim -f` option. These commands didn't work for me, and based on Vim's documentation, I don't believe they should when Vim is run in a terminal. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Additionally, I know that I could probably accomplish my goal by combining the Vim remote commands with a shell command that interacts with windows (e.g. `xdotool` or `wmctrl`). But I'm wondering if there's a better (and preferably native) way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, other than by the methods you have already suggested.

I don't think Vim knows whether or not the terminal it is in has focus, and it definitely has no method of changing the window manager's state (except [shell](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3A!)/[system](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) commands such as those you mention).